How can I force robot framework to stop connecting to the internet to check for browser drivers and use one I have downloaded?
We are trying to use Robot Framework in a corporate environment where there are multiple firewalls etc blocking internet access for anything other than a Chrome window (even then we have to sign into a website before internet access is allowed). We're trying to test websites using Robot Framework but hitting a bump as every time we start the tests, it fails as it cannot find a chrome driver. We're limited to what we can do as we cannot change system PATH variables either. What we're trying to do is somehow include a chrome driver exe file in our robot framework test files folder somewhere which the resource file can grab and use as the chrome driver. Is this something which is possible? I have tried using OperatingSystem library to set a PATH to the chrome driver exe file but still get the same error saying Selenium Manager cannot find the chrome driver. Thanks!

Hello, quick google search gave me these: using Create Webdriver and using webdriver-manager

I think if you put the chromedriver inside your root project and working directory the robot framework would see it.
